# Ionic 2: InAppBrowser plugin is not installed, although I installed it

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I'm using Ionic 2 and need to open a page in an InAppBrowser.

I used `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` to install the InAppBrowser. When I execute it second time, I get:

```
Plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" already installed on android.
Plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" already installed on ios.
```

I uploaded the app via `ionic package build android` to Ionic Cloud. I downloaded and installed the app on my Nexus 5, connected via Chrome DevTools to my phone, checked the console which tells me `Native: tried calling InAppBrowser.open, but the InAppBrowser plugin is not installed.`

Any idea whats wrong?